# Circuit distorting AC signal from CT

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

Below the 60Hz signal from the CT only with the burden resistor connected:

[image]

When I connect it to the opamp circuit, this is what it becomes:

[image]

Some points about the circuit below:

1. x1,x2 - z1-z2 are analog switches: SN74LVC2G66DCUR
2. L1 L2 are two identical secondaries from the same CT. One is used for sensing and the other is occasionally used for testing.
3. D12 sets the DC offset to Vcc/2

My guess is that the culprit here is related to the analog switch. Any light on this?

[image]

Comment: 2nd picture - where do you measure?

Comment: Both 1st and 2nd picture are measured across the burden. The difference is the 2nd is connected as shown in the 3rd picture. The 1st is just using the burden with no other circuitry.

Comment: See what voltage is on TP9.

Comment: 1.65V as expected, i.e., 3.3/2.

Comment: I mean is there any superimposed AC on TP9

Comment: No. I don't see a superimposed AC

Comment: Was the op-amp input connected when you did this?

Comment: All is good now. I disconnected L2 and the circuit behaves OK. I guess I have to redesign the circuit for L2. Also, I had to lower R31 as it was too high and the reference was distorted.

Answer (score 0):

The output is between -1 and +1 V, and since the test coil is biased to 0V GND on one terminal, the input to LVC2G66 would go between -1 and +1, but that input is beyond LVC2G66 supplies and the IO pin protection diodes will clamp the signal at about -0.5V.

Comment: So should I bias the test coil L2 as L1?

Comment: That would be a solution, yes.

Comment: What other solution you would suggest?

Comment: I think that is the simplest solution, so I have no other solutions to suggest. Is there something wrong with that solution, or why do you need other solutions?

Comment: Actually no. I'm going to test that solution and report results.

Comment: Tp7 goes +- 1 volt wrt Tp9 .Double check the DC volts on Tp9.

Comment: What Opamp have you used? not a 324?? .

Comment: It's not a 324. It's a OPA317.

Comment: @Justme A question... The test_square signal to the test winding comes from a micro. The current from the micro has to return to the micro through ground and if I reference L2 to the VCC/2 point as L1 then the return current may affect the reference. What do you think on this?

Comment: True, the bias generator works at 0.5mA and the coil drive is +/- 3.3mA so in fact it is not that simple. Move the AC coupling to other side of the mux, and bias it weakly with a resistor divider to half supply so there is no need to load the precision reference?